# Excel formula: output values based on matched data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a range of dates column A, and a number of selected dates column C. My logic would be "If a cell of A contains same value as C, then output the same row field of B into D, starting at D1 and contining downward."

What would be the best syntax to accomplish this?

I have tried to use an IF(VLOOKUP()) to do this, but I don't understand how it really works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have this

```
A         |B    |C         |D
01/01/2015|hello|01/01/2015|
```

then the formula in D should be `VLOOKUP(C1,A:B,2,FALSE)`

This means 'find the value C1 in column A (the first of the two columns A:B) and then give me the value from the second column (B)'. Note the use of `FALSE` which means you are looking for an exact match.

---

[image: Excel]

---

You can enter the following formula in D1 and then drag it down as far as you need it ...

```
=VLOOKUP(C1,A:B,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: I appreciate the response. Oddly enough, this returns N/A, despite C1 and A1 having both '12/1/2008' as a value. Your table is accurate to what I have.

Comment: With a bit of fiddling, VLOOKUP (C:C,A:B,2,FALSE) works as you intended. Thanks. How would one repeat this so that it continues through all of A?

Comment: I've updated my answer using just row 1 ... I would try this on a new sheet ... you may find your dates have a time component that is stopping the comparison working correctly.